# rails 2.3 config.load_paths in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I moved some files into subfolders within my app/models directory and added those directories in the config.load_paths in config/environment.rb:

```
config.load_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/extras"]
```

within app/models/extras I've got a few ActiveRecord models, for instance say:

app/models/extras/blog_post.rb

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

app/models/extras/comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
end
```

Now when I call a page (ie. /blog_posts/) where only BlogPosts are shown (without loading the comments association) everything works fine
But if I call a page (ie. /blog_posts/1) where the comments are included in the queries (like, BlogPost.find(1, :include => :comments), I get the following error:

```
Expected .../app/models/extras/comment.rb to define Extras::Comment
```

Now everything works fine in production mode, but not in development.. Anyone has a fix or a solution for this?

Comment: If you move this model & the load_path completely out of /app/models/, does he still throw this error?

Comment: moved it to app/lib and i don't get that error anymore

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because rails maps the module structure to directories, so, for example, it expects comment.rb in models/extras to actually be in the namespace Extras, i.e. defined as Extras::Comment.  You should be able to manually load the directory via a require to load statement from w/in BlogPost or the controller where you need it